# Metadata dependency error

Tags: deployment, metadata

Hello everyone please help me if anyone faced this issue.
So I have backup of an org but I don't have access to that org anymore.
There are lots of metadata so how can I get the dependencies with the help of backup and how can I migrate it to new sandbox avoiding dependencies error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since both, the orgs might have different features and settings it won’t be just dependencies of metadata that can fail the deployment. Deployment can fail if you don’t replicate the right features and settings!

It is not possible to determine metadata dependency correctly if you lost the org!

One way to make progress is by brute-forcing the deployment. (by manipulating the metadata XML of the component that's failing to bypass the error)

You will deploy and if faced with an issue you will troubleshoot and then remove the offending metadata XML element and try again till you succeed!

> You will need to have knowledge of Salesforce Metadata to do this work. Metadata API Developer Guide will be your [friend](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/).